# Angular not working on div loaded with jquery load function

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs

I have master page which has script for angularJs and a div which acts as a parent div to load the html page which is created using angular.

**ParentPage.aspx**

```
<script src="../../Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Controller For Angular Page -->
<script src="../../Scripts/Controller/PartialRegistrationController.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("module", []);

    function partialRegistrationForm() { // Function to Initiate load call      
        $('#divFullRegistration').load('../RegistrationPages/PartialRegistration.htm', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
</script>

<div id="divPopupRegistration" class="RegistrationPopup hide" style="overflow: hidden;z-index: 999" ng-app="module">
    <div id="divFullRegistration" class="Full hide">
    </div>
</div>
```

**PartialRegistration.htm**

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
<body ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="partialcontroller" id="parentDiv" ng-init="init()">
        <div class="registrationBg" runat="server" id="PartialRegistration">

        // Some HTML

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have some angular textbox and drop down which gets data from server. I can see empty dropdown in html page.

**It works When** i put `<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>` in `PartialRegistration.htm`

But angular script is already loaded in ParentPage.aspx, so why this issue is coming ?

Comment: call your partialRegistrationForm func in your angular app.run function.

Comment: @YOU any code snippet ?

Comment: `app.run(function(){ ............ });`

Comment: It sounds like you really want a directive called `partial-registration` that uses `PartialRegistration.htm` as its template. If you only want to load after something has happened in scope, you can use `ng-if` for that.

Comment: why don't bind load event from directive on that `divFullRegistration` element.

Comment: @pankajparkar Guyz can u help me with code, i m newbie in angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should bind event using directive rather than using jQuery code

**Markup**

```
<div id="divFullRegistration" class="Full hide" my-directive></div>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    compile: function(element, attrs){
      //here your all jQuery code will lie to ensure binding
      element.load('../RegistrationPages/PartialRegistration.htm', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that angular is not notified that anything just happened. You must create a directive or use the $[compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service and pass any $scope before adding the template

```
$compile(html)($scope);
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me. I wrapped my jQuery in this like so: `$compile($('#profile-builder').html(resp.data.html))($scope);`.